# Making onclick value as the identifier of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently struggling on a form without ID

it is coded like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal()" type="button">Browse Data</button>
```

and I have no way to control the onclick function

I am thinking of customizing it on my way. Can I put it like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').attr('onclick') == 'showModal()' .on('click', function(){
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

Comment: Aside from the syntax issues, this approach is a bad idea. It would make more sense to select the element by it's parent structure, ie `#container .something > button`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think the syntax would be something like $( "button[attr='showModal()'" ).on("click", function(){...}); but as already said this is not a good idea

Comment: Do you need to superceed the showModal functionality, or add further logic while keeping the original functionality?/

Comment: I would like to control that button. I can't control it because it doesn't have any identifier and there's other button on that page but all with only onclick functions.

Comment: Basically, I have created my own modal. I would like to attach it onto that button. I am not able to edit the source file because I am currently using a form generator in Laravel called Crudbooster.

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
        if($(this).attr('onclick') == 'showModal()') {
            alert('test');
        }        
    });
});
```

However, this is wrong on many many levels!

Comment: Code seems good. However, can you tell me why is it wrong? I would like to learn what will be the bad scenario for this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this method?

**Code Snippets:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[onclick = "showModal()"]').on('click', function() {
    alert('test');
  });
});

function showModal() {
  alert("Inline Click method");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal()" type="button">Browse Data</button>
```